# Currency Rate not importing from Webservicex in magento 2

Tags: magento2, web-services, currency-rates

[image]

I checked it at my localhost as well as on liver server.

Is this bug or anything is missing by me ?

> I seems that same things is not working into magento1.x too. Is this
>   problem into Webservicex api or into stable version ?

Comment: Is there any error you see in the log or in the admin panel when you press save? And yeah, the Webservicex Api is not the most stable one. Downtime is possible.

Comment: Not found any log. But feel tha the issue from API.

Answer (score 3):

WebserviceX has been down for some time now. Its API is now returning a -1 for all currency conversions.

You can test it here if you want: http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate

I suggest you switch to another currency API.

Fixer.io is now available on Magento 2 out of the box and can be used instead of WebserviceX.

Answer (score 2):

[Fixer.io](http://fixer.io/) as additional currency converter service has been added into Magento2.